# The definition for "knp_paginator" has no class

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

hi i installed the KnpPaginatorBundle in py project and i flow all the steps in the documentation, the problem is when i open the page i got this exception :

> RuntimeException in CheckDefinitionValidityPass.php line 63: The
>   definition for "knp_paginator" has no class. If you intend to inject
>   this service dynamically at runtime, please mark it as synthetic=true.
>   If this is an abstract definition solely used by child definitions,
>   please add abstract=true, otherwise specify a class to get rid of this
>   error.